# How to Sqoop Import as JSON?

Tags: sqoop

I am aware Sqoop supports importing data as Avro, as Parquet, as Text etc.  Is there a way to import data as JSON?

Using Spark is not an option for me at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop does not support importing JSON files. You can import it as textfiles into HDFS and parse it using Python/scala.